# How to clip a widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to achieve something looking like this (top right)

[image]

but my clipping ability is off.

```
class CardClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(size.width *.8, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    


    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    
    

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```dart
class CardClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final corderWidth = 12.0;

  final radius = const Radius.circular(12);
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    const littleCorner = 10.0;

    path
      ..moveTo(corderWidth, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width * .8, 0)
      // top Right S
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * .8 + (littleCorner / 2),
        0,
        size.width * .8 + littleCorner,
        littleCorner / 4,
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width - littleCorner, size.height * .2)
      // top Right E
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width - (littleCorner / 2),
        size.height * .2 + (littleCorner / 2),
        size.width,
        size.height * .2 + littleCorner * 2,
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - corderWidth)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(size.width - corderWidth, size.height),
          radius: radius)
      ..lineTo(corderWidth, size.height)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(0, size.height - corderWidth), radius: radius)
      ..lineTo(0, corderWidth)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(corderWidth, 0), radius: radius);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Little ,can be improved on `quadraticBezierTo` (Right E)

[image]

You can use this path

```dart
class CardClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final corderWidth = 12.0;

  final radius = Radius.circular(12);
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path
      ..moveTo(corderWidth, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width * .8, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height * .2)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - corderWidth)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(size.width - corderWidth, size.height),
          radius: radius)
      ..lineTo(corderWidth, size.height)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(0, size.height - corderWidth), radius: radius)
      ..lineTo(0, corderWidth)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(corderWidth, 0), radius: radius);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: cool, mind to round those sharp ends too though

Comment: Top right part?

Comment: yes please.. :)